# Python list output

Tags: python

Quiz on Tutorials Point list the following question?
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_online_quiz.htm

> Q 9 - What is the output of L[-2] if L = [1,2,3]?
>
> A - 1
>
> B - 2
>
> C - 3
>
> D - None of the above.
>
> Answer : A Explanation 1, Negative: count from the right.

They are saying the answer is 1,  but when I run the following in idle I get output of 2

```
L = [1,2,3]
print (L[-2])

output 2
```

is this a error on tutorial point or is it error in idle ?

My python version is 2.7

Comment: there should have been a newline between the print statement but for some reason I guess copy and paste did not sort that out.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.   I too was getting 2 in my head , sense list starts from 0 and counts up, so first element would be index0 etc,  so doing in in reverse made sense answer should be 2.

Comment: That quiz is rubbish. They even have questions like "What is the following function compares elements of both dictionaries dict1, dict2?"(sic!) with the answer "`cmp(dict1, dict2)` − Compares elements of both dict.".

Comment: Clearly I should avoid Tutorial Point for learning python.  Can you offer a better alternative that has quizes to test my learned knowledge .  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Quiz should be wrong.

L[-1] refers to the last element of the list, 1. Therefore, L[-2] should refer to 2.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `L = [1,2,3]`, we know that their elements positions are:

```
number 1 =  position 0
number 2 =  position 1
number 3 =  position 2
```

So `L[-2]` is equal to `2`, because:

Counting Forward:

```
L[0] = number 1
L[1] = number 2
L[2] = number 3
```

Counting Backward:

```
L[-1] = number 3
L[-2] = number 2
L[-3] = number 1
```

So... I think your quiz answer is wrong. The correct answer for `L[-2]` is the alternative `B-2`.